# What is the English word or phrase for "nihithawan"? NA Cree word

Tags: word-meaning

What is the English translation of the NA plains Cree word >nihithawan  as found in Rosanna Deerchild's  novel *Calling Down The Sky*, page 5?
Our book club is studying this novel and we cannot find the Cree (NA Plains) to English translation on line anywhere.  We cannot guess its meaning by its context either.

Thank you for helping us out, if you can or cannot, the effort would be greatly appreciated.

Blessings

Wendy Noll

..

Comment: You're going to have to give a definition for the Cree word. What does it mean? (And if *you* don't know what it means, we certainly can't provide an English equivalent on this site.) Can you at least quote the sentence in which it's placed?

Comment: Strangely, a google search for **nihithawan** brings up results for the Cree language, without that word being available.

Comment: *Calling Down the Sky* doesn't appear to be a novel, but a collection of poetry, which just about guarantees that it is impossible for us to suggest a translation without additional context. What is the exact text, please? Have you tried comparing the English translation with the French translation, perhaps?

Comment: Updated my answer after response from author

Comment: Thank you so much. Everyone was so helpful and we received the answers we needed.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote to the author who told me simply it means "**Speak Cree**".

The following is my tiny amount of understanding of Cree from Wikipedia pages and other online resources.

- **Nihithawak** means the Cree people, in th-dialect Cree ([ref](https://press.uottawa.ca/wild-plant-use-by-the-woods-cree-nihithawak-of-east-central-saskatchewan-pdf.html))
- **Nihithawan** means "Speak Cree", in th-dialect Cree (author email)

Woods Cree is *Nīhithawīwin*, ᓀᐦᐃᖬᐍᐏᐣ‎ in Woods Cree. ([ref](https://www.ethnologue.com/language/cwd))

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Cree_syllabics): Cree is syllabic and highly inflected, and comes in a number of dialects, including "th-dialect" and "y-dialect" ([ref](https://creeliteracy.org/2019/05/04/traditional-foods/)). Only Woods Cree has *th* (written as *y* syllables modified with a crossbar) and also *e* has merged with *i*.

So Woods Cree **Nihitha-** might be **Nehiya-** in other forms of Cree.

A [Cree dictionary](http://www.creedictionary.com) gives some support to this:

- *nehiyawak* ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐊᐧᐠ NA the Cree people (EC)
- *nehiyawewin* ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐁᐧᐃᐧᐣ N The Cree language. (MD)

The inflections of Cree include prefixes, infixes, suffixes and can be compound.  The dictionary gives two which illustrate the complexity.

- *nehiyawe* ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐁᐧ VC Speak Cree. (MD)
- *nêhiyawêmototawêw* ᓀᐦᐃᔭᐁᐧᒧᑐᑕᐁᐧᐤ VTA s/he speak Cree to s.o. (CW)

This entire question is probably better suited to [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Very,very cool but sort of off-topic.....But I would let it slide since we need to give back to Amerindians any way we can.